# find minimum of my own class queue

Tags: c++

I create class queue and I need to find minimum and maximum. The maximum is correct, but minimum isn't. For what number should I change value of 
 head  and tail to get correct result? If I change them for zero , the first element becomes both maximum and minimum 
[queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYR1P.png)

```
class myQueue
{
private:
    int size, head, tail, *data;
    public:
    myQueue(int size = 1) :
            size(size)
    {
        data = new int[size];
        head = -1;
        tail = -1;
    }

    ~myQueue() //
    {
        delete[] data;
    }

    void myEnqueue(int el)
    {
        data[tail] = el;
        tail = (tail + 1) % size;
    }

    int maxEl()
    {
        int *temp = &data[head];
        int max = *temp;
        while (*temp != data[tail])
        {
            temp++;
            max = (max > *temp) ? max : *temp;
        }
        return max;
    }

    int minEl()
    {
        int *temp = &data[head];
        int min = *temp;
        while (*temp != data[tail])
        {
            temp++;
            min = (min < *temp) ? min : *temp;
        }
        return min;
    }
};
int main()
{
    myQueue q(5);
    int n = 0, el;
    while (n < 5)
    {
        cin >> el;
        q.myEnqueue(el);
        n++;
    }
    cout << "The arithmetic mean of the elements = " << q.srArifm(5) << "\n";
    cout << "Maximum queue element = " << q.maxEl() << "\n";
    cout << "Minimum queue element =" << q.minEl() << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tail` is `-1` after the object is constructed.

When you add first element your method `MyQueue::myEnqueue` does something like this:

```
data[-1]=el;
```

Your last element always has garbage in it which is potentially big negative number. `Head` being -1 is also a bad idea.

Fix:

1. Your head and tail should be `0`
2. You code of adding the elements should be:

   ```
   if (tail == size)
   {
       tail = 0;
   }
   data[tail++] = el;
   ```

Comment: for what number should I change value of head and tail to get correct result? if I change them for zero , the first element becomes both maximum and minimum

Comment: @choko check my latest edit. This version handles replacing elements when the queue is full properly